# The session_start () and $ _SESSION command is not working

Tags: php, html, forms, session, authentication

I'm not able to start session_start () in php and I really can't understand the reason, I've tried a few things people suggested on forums, but the session_start() still does not work

index file where are not retrieving variables $ _SESSION:

```js
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pagina1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <article id="newPrincipal">
        <h1>Usuário id:<?php echo $_SESSION['userId']; ?></h1> 
    </article>
    <h1>Result:<?php echo "Usuário id:".$_SESSION['userId']; ?></h1>
</body>

</html>
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION['userId']);
echo '</pre>';
```

login file:

```js
<?php

if(isset($_POST['login-submit'])){

    require 'dbh.inc.php';

   $users = $_POST['nome'];
    $mailuid = $_POST['mailuid'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $token;
    if(empty($mailuid) || empty($password)){
        header("Location: ../header.php=emptyfields");
        exit();
    }
    else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Usuarios=? AND email=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
            header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        }
        else{
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $users);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
                if($pwdCheck == false){
                    header("Location: ../header.php?error=wrongpwd");
                    exit();
                }
                else if($pwdCheck == true){
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
                    $_SESSION['userId2'] = $row['uidUsers'];
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['emailUsers'];

                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=".$_SESSION['userId']);
                }
                else{
                    header("Location: ../login.php?error=wrongpwd");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else{
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

I'm using an external server not the Xampp / Wamp, I do not know if this would imply anything ...

I tried every ways to retrieve some information using $ _SESSION in the index file, but I could not.

Comment: Your session will only start in the 2nd body of code if all conditions are met. Enable error reporting and check for errors on the query.

Comment: `session_start();` **should always be at the TOP of your code**

Comment: And your `index.php` should be generating an error as when that runs there will be nothing in $_SESSION as no login has been done yet. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors

Comment: Riggsfolly and Funk Forty Nine thanks for replying. I did everything you asked me to, but it's still not working, you know the best way to find out if have any errors in the code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that you are calling `session_start();` and checking for possible session errors on both pages, make sure the first three lines of code on both pages are the following:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); //will show session errors (if any)
session_start(); //starts the session and makes $_SESSION variables available
```

Then, in your login file, change the code where you set the `$_SESSION` variables to match the following:

```
...
else if($pwdCheck == true){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
    $_SESSION['userId2'] = $row['uidUsers'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['emailUsers'];

    //test output
    echo "The $_SESSION['userID'] variable is set as: " & $_SESSION['userID'];

    exit;

    //comment the redirect out for now, so that you see the test output
    //header("Location: ../index.php?login=".$_SESSION['userId']);
}
...
```

In the comments, let me know if you get any errors and what the test output for the login file is.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Justin. I added session_start () at the top of the script, even though it is not working !!

Comment: I just updated my solution again, I noticed another small error. Please try this and let me know if it is working.

Comment: the parameters were correct, I have no idea why the session does not work, when I ask to print the $ _SESSION ['userId'] in the login script it works, but when I ask to print in sript index it does not work

Comment: At the end of your index file, it looks like you open the PHP tag, but you do not close it. Add the closing PHP tag (`?>`) to the very end of the index file. Also, try using `echo $_SESSION['userId'];` instead of `print_r($_SESSION['userId']);`

Comment: did not work. Anyway, thanks for your help, I give up!

Comment: I am not giving up on you! I just updated my solution, we will get this working!

Comment: you are awesome ! But I think you have no problem with the code. I tried to see if I conceived a result using XAMPP and everything went well as I wanted, using XAMPP the $ session gave me the information I requested ... the problem was with the hosting server and it's already resolved. Anyway, thank you for helping me! <3

Comment: Excellent, I am glad you were able to get it working! Good luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: Thanks !!!  ^_^b